# Excel file . xlsx can't join with the shapefile map layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

Trying to join a shapefile layer - polygons - (municipalities with a data table with corresponding data sets) an Excel file with the .xlsx extension, BUT as showed in the attached image some error occurs.

Any suggestions what's wrong with this join procedure?

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom. Please take the [tour] and put some more detail in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Please explain the question in more detail but seeing how this issue comes up again over time I believe the issue is with the Excel file. Try exporting the .xlsx file to a .csv file then join. 
ArcMap does not like .xlsx files (you can also try a .xls filetype)

In addition, downloading the 2007 Office System Driver will rectify many issues with excel files.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734